# Testing Android browser without the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm working on a javascript framework that generates webkit browser pages which emulate a native app for Android & iPhone.

I'm using an iPhone emulator (iBBPhone -- very nice) to see how my pages would look on the iPhone and iPad.  I was curious if there was something besides the Android SDK phone emulator that would simulate the Android browsing experience. I'm using desktop Google Chrome right now as a "pretend Android" browser but I'm not sure how alike they really are.

The Android emulator that ships with the SDK is a bit too slow to fire up on my box to be of great use in what I'm doing (even when starting up a saved image), and I was curious if there was anything else out there that simulates Android browsing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think [this Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) will let you display the site as it would show up in several different types of browsers. I know it supports iPhone so I imagine it will do Android as well. [This page](http://www.mobilestartup.com/2007/04/firefox_plugins_for_mobile_web.html) also talks about some other Firefox plug-ins that may be useful to you.

Comment: This only switches the user agent string, not the rendering or JavaScript engine. Not useful at all.

Comment: this is not what we need. it changes only user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a nice add-on named Ripple that does the job nicely I've found.  http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/

Comment: needs more development and a better explination of install. found this link useless

Comment: `"The Ripple podling retired on 2015-12-06."`

Answer (score 1):

These guys pretend to meet this need. Might be a good idea to check it out.

http://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator